# Как подгрузить php-скрипт посредством загружаемого изображения?

Tags: php, html, cross-domain

Есть два сайта с разными доменами под моим контролем. Задача - получить данные с сайта `1.com` на сайте `2.com`. Один из способов: загрузить изображение из `1.com` привязав к нему php-скрипт.

Прошу совета по синтаксису, потому что я понимаю, что делаю неправильно:

Домен **1.com**, файл `proxy.php`:

```
<?php
 $data = "123";
 echo $data;
?>
```

Домен **2.com**, файл `index.html`:

```
<img src="http://1.com/img.png?data=<?php echo 1.com/proxy.php ; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно модифицировать ваш скрипт на

**2.com**

```
<img src="http://1.com/img.png?data=<?php echo file_get_contents('https://1.com/proxy.php'); ?>" />
```

Тоесть, через функцию `file_get_contents` вы получаете строку ответа сервера
 **1.com/proxy.php** и потом уже её добавляете к ссылке

### Ответ на комментарий, как передать cookie

Когда запускается скрипт через PHP, вы можете взять куку текущей сессии из глобальной переменной [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, принято. Жаль, что так нельзя передавать куки (на самом деле вопрос был связан с ними). Т.е. если в переменную я записываю куку, то скрипт не передает эту переменную, а любую другую - передает. Если знаете как передать куку, подскажите, пожалуйста, в комментарии.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, я обновил ответ

Comment: Или же вам нужно получить куки другого вебсайта?

Comment: Нужно подтянуть куку из сайта 1.com, но не получается. (Вероятно, что куки и вовсе нельзя передать сервером, поскольку это клиентская переменная). Т.е. передать из 1.com в 2.com можно всё что угодно кроме переменных из массивов $_COOKIE и $_SESSION.